# How to get observable in aurelia value binding behaviour

Tags: aurelia

So I have a binding behaviour and I want to subscribe to the actual value changing, so I know I can use the `observerLocator` but I am not entirely sure how to get the value to observe, hopefully its a simple question.

Comment: Do you want to observe the value from inside the binding behaviour class? Can you use the bindingEngine? https://gist.run/?id=c1e102d1cb1a252d9c3f2ad96a620a39

Comment: What do you provide to the `bindingEngine.propertyObserver` though, I can get an `observerLocator` or whatever they are called and do the same with that to subscribe, but I don't know how to provide it the current variable in scope, as you would either need the observable value for the `observerLocator` or the containing object and the name of the property for `bindingEngine` so that is the crux of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A binding will update the target (the view) and optionally the source (the view-model) if it's a two-way binding.

A binding behavior can intercept these updates by overriding the binding's `updateTarget(value)` and `updateSource(value)` methods.

Take a look at the [custom binding behaviors](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/7) section of the docs for examples. There are also examples in the [validation](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/validate-binding-behavior-base.ts) and templating-resources packages.